# Domain of differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I made some function for plotting Domain of differential equation , will show how it works for $y'=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$

```
g = Sqrt[1 - x^2];  h = Sqrt[1 - y^2];
f = g/h;
vars = {x, y};
ssp1 = NSolve[{g == 0, h == 0}, vars];
ssp = Values[ssp1];
DomainDJ[f_, vars_] := 
  RegionUnion[ImplicitRegion[FunctionDomain[f, vars], Evaluate@vars], 
   ImplicitRegion[FunctionDomain[1/f, vars], Evaluate@vars]];

PlotDomainDJSP[f_, vars_, sp_] := Module[{df}, spt = Transpose[sp];


   df = DomainDJ[f, vars];

   Show[
        RegionPlot[df],
        ListPlot[sp, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]]
        ]
                                        ];

PlotDomainDJSP[f, vars, ssp]
```

[image]

Thats Domain of that Differential equation . 
I got few question.

(The idea why is not simple show region plot is because regionplot do not show that singular points are not in region , so i made some extra Listplot to show us it )

1. How i can make to make large space on Plot, for example if is Domain from -1
2. Can i make in that function also GeneralSolution=DSolve[...] ,so then plot that General Solution and finaly Show[ (all 3 (domain of d.e ,listpoint with singular points ,general solution] .

   I cant DSolve[f,y[x],x] , because in $f$ is not y[x] (its y ) , if i
   try to change g=y[x]... or something like f=y[x]... my function for
   ploting will not work.

Comment: Change f to f /. y -> y[x] inside DSolve

Comment: You think DSolve[{y'[x] == f /. y -> y[x]}, y[x], x] ?

Comment: Probably better with parentheses: `DSolve[{y'[x] == (f /. y -> y[x])}, y[x], x]`

Comment: Ye it works ,have you an idea for 1. question ?

Comment: I didnt write good in question . 

1. How i can make to make large space on Plot, for example if is Domain from -1<x<1 & -1<y<1   then my Plot start from -2<x<2& -2<y<2 etc ?

Comment: `PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}`?  Look up `PlotRangePadding`, too.